# How to install gcov that is compatible with gcc version 10.1?

Tags: 18.04, gcc, g++, compiler

I'm trying to use CLions interface to `gcov` but I'm not using the default g++ compiler (for Ubuntu 18.04). Therefore my version of `gcov` (7.5) is incompatible with my compiler (10.1).

How can I install `gcov` that works with `gcc` / `g++ 10.1` ?

I've tried:

- sudo apt install gcov
- sudo apt install gcov-10
- sudo apt install gcov-dev

Comment: What is gcov? Which repository do you use / plan to use to install it? I do not see exact `gcov` packages in standard repositories, they have only [`ggcov`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=gcov).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar issue and I found a way to update gcov between gcc 7 and 8 which needed a gcov and gcovr update as well as different versions of python (python 3). see more details here: [how-to-update-install-gcovr-to-match-my-updated-compiler-gcc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65581636/how-to-update-install-gcovr-to-match-my-updated-compiler-gcc/65584788#65584788)

Hopefully this answers your question if you have not answered it yourself after 6 months :)

Comment: haha yeah I gave up on this a long time ago.

Answer (score 0):

```
              sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
              sudo apt-get update
              sudo apt-get install -y gcc-10 g++-10
              sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-10 1
```